# Turning off file cache in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, cache

ArcGIS Pro caches the contents of files even after the file has been replaced on disk.

How can this feature be disabled?

Comment: Have you looked on the Project Page where many options can be set?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/set-layer-properties.htm 'turn off'